# xhost: "libXmuu.1.dylib" library not loaded

Tags: x11, xquartz

I'm attempting to add my local IP address to `xhost` and I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXmuu.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/xhost
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/X11/lib/libXmuu.1.dylib: code signature in (/opt/X11/lib/libXmuu.1.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapping process is a platform binary, but mapped file is not
    /opt/X11/lib/libXmuu.1.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
Abort trap: 6
```

The error occurs even when just calling `xhost` from the command line. However, I it seems to be installed and in the correct place. The output of `which xhost` results in `/usr/bin/xhost`

I'm working on a fresh install of XQuartz and CommandLineTools. I've tried downgrading XQuartz, logging out and back in as well as rebooting after each fresh install. Still no luck.

This appears to be a [documented issue](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109211), though I can't find any answers for fixes.

**Operating System**: OSX 10.14.5 on MacBook Pro, 2018

**XQuartz Version**: 2.7.11

### Edit

Output of `codesign -vvv -d /usr/bin/xhost`:

```
Executable=/usr/bin/xhost
Identifier=xhost
Format=Mach-O universal (i386 x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=261 flags=0x0(none) hashes=4+2 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=ddd40d822185d02bc484aae27ab8a2a832490c9f
CandidateCDHash sha256=5c76bf6e89fc30926f3d38559f9cf813bcf63349
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
CDHash=5c76bf6e89fc30926f3d38559f9cf813bcf63349
Signature size=8928
Authority=Developer ID Application: Apple Inc. - XQuartz (NA574AWV7E)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=Oct 7, 2016 at 1:26:16 PM
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=NA574AWV7E
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=168
```

Comment: Did you follow the crossed out link at the very end: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109168 ; it may provide additional information for you.

Comment: /usr/bin/xhost doesn't ship with macOS.  Where did you get it from?  Just run /opt/local/bin/xhost.

Comment: Please also provide the output of `codesign -vvv -d /usr/bin/xhost`

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I believe xhost came with XQuartz, though I could be wrong. Either way, I updated my question with the output your requested. Thanks!

Comment: /opt/local/bin/xhost comes with XQuartz.  /usr/bin/xhost absolutely does not come with XQuartz nor macOS.

Comment: It looks like you (or someone) copied /opt/X11/bin/xhost to /usr/bin.  Any idea how that happened?

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked is specifying the correct path for xhost:

```
/usr/X11/bin/xhost + 127.0.0.1
```

(macOS)